# How to connect a JS verticle and a Java verticle?

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle

I am creating a Vertx verticle in JS(nodeJS) using es4x or vertx3-full package. I am using npm because of a npm-specific package. Now I have another verticle written in Java. I want these verticles to connect. How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

From Vertx [documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_verticles)

> An application would typically be composed of many verticle instances
> running in the same Vert.x instance at the same time. The different
> verticle instances communicate with each other by sending messages on
> the event bus.

So basically you can

send a message from one verticle using `eventBus.send(ADDRESS, message, sendMessageHander)` and

consume it from the other verticle using `eventBus.consumer(ADDRESS, receivedMessageHandler)`

There is a fully runnable open source example [here](https://github.com/hakdogan/IntroduceToEclicpseVert.x/tree/master/messenger)
There is also publish/subscribe message patter that you can find in the [documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_publish_subscribe_messaging).

Comment: Can you share an example with one JS verticle and  one Java verticle? My verticles are unable to detect each other when I publish from one and consume from other.

Comment: you need to deploy the verticles in the same context. With the example in the answer, check the files https://github.com/hakdogan/IntroduceToEclicpseVert.x/blob/master/messenger/src/main/java/com/kodcu/nonclustered/messenger/verticle/MessengerLauncher.java and https://github.com/hakdogan/IntroduceToEclicpseVert.x/blob/master/messenger/src/main/java/com/kodcu/nonclustered/messenger/main/Starter.java

Comment: @TcheutchouaSteve how can this be save if it will be exposed on the internet (in browser). This will mean that everyone (every client) will be able to push messages on the bus? I think it will be easy to push malicious messages tp the event bus right? Can the event bus be protected somehow? Maybe some authentication or something like this?

Comment: @Adrian if you are using a vertx version above 3.3 you can secure communication with SSL https://vertx.io/blog/vert-x-3-3-0-is-released/